# which OpenSSL version is used in bouncycastle library?

Tags: openssl, bouncycastle

I am using BouncyCastle Library for OpenSSL encryption in Android.
My library version is 1.45.

I would like to know the OpenSSL version is used in the library. Anybody can help me how could I find it out ?

Comment: bouncycastle != openssl. openssl is not used by bouncycastle and bouncycastle is not used by openssl. They are completely independent. Android uses both.

Comment: From the below link : http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html you can see that bouncycastle library contains openSSL library. I would like to know which OpenSSL version is implemented in this library.

Comment: You are severely confused. Once again, and for the last time, it does not contain the openssl library.

Comment: @Nirav, there appears to be an [`org.bouncycastle.openssl`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/index.html?org/bouncycastle/openssl/) package in `bcpkix`. Are you referring to that?

Comment: Yes...I mean to that folder...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BouncyCastle implement with java.

It doesn't need OpenSSL at all.

org.bouncycastle.openssl package in bcpkix is use to handle the PEM file generated by OpenSSL.

https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/package-summary.html