# Which version of OpenSSL does Bouncy Castle use?

Tags: openssl, bouncycastle

I am trying to figure out which version of OpenSSL is used by Bouncy Castle.
I did a lot of web search, but to no avail.

The version o bouncy castle which i am using is

- bcprov-jdk15-1.46.jar
- bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar

Which version of OpenSSL does Bouncy Castle use?

Answer (score 2):

BouncyCastle is a library to include in your programming language. It does not use openssl at runtime at all

Check [which OpenSSL version is used in bouncycastle library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744331/which-openssl-version-is-used-in-bouncycastle-library)